# Android SQLite add duplicate item

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on sqllite. I've created the database successfully, and I can add new items to it.

```
// Adding new contact
public void Add_Contact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_Tittle, contact.getTitle()); // Contact title
    values.put(KEY_Description, contact.getDescription()); // Contact
                                                            // description

    values.put(KEY_Price, contact.getPrice()); // Contact price

    values.put(KEY_Image, contact.getImage()); // Contact image
    values.put(KEY_Counter, contact.getCounter()); // Contact counter
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);

    Log.e("Table Result isss", String.valueOf(values));
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

This code working perfect, now I want to check if I can also save the same information, for example, if I first save "Hello Android" and in a second time try to save the same information, I want to show for example: Toast message or other.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: How is you DB setup? (the create table sql statement). Is the duplicate data inserting enforced by the database?

Comment: @user3742085: Check my answer below. I hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

**First make a function like this:**

```
public boolean somethingExists(String x) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select 1 from " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " where KEY_Tittle like '%" + x
                + "%'", null);
        boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
        cursor.close();
        return exists;
    }
```

**And then before every insert call this funcition to return if it exists or not like this:**

```
if (!somethingExists("hello world")) {
     //HERE DO INSERTION if it is not already in Table e.g like call AddContact function here for insertion etc
} else {
    //Display Toast message here "Record already exists"
}
```

p.s i just wanted to highlight the logic - your actual table names, schema & logic might be different. Anyways, try this - it should work. The actually working is supposed to follow all database constraints, structure and schema of your design.